# Step counter doesn't reset the step count

Tags: android, counter, reset, android-sensors

I am able to start and stop recording steps with the `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` by registering and unregistering the listener.

However, the actual value that is passed to my app via the `SensorEvent` object does not reset to zero when the application is destroyed. If I close the app and restart it, or even if I recompile my app with updates, the counter picks up where it left off.

If I run other apps that use the step counter sensor, they independently count their steps and reset their counter.

Does the sensor have a cache that is app specific?  What is the correct way to reset the sensor to zero steps counted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Android Sensor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER):

> **public static final int TYPE_STEP_COUNTER**
>
> A sensor of this type **returns the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated**. The value is returned as a float (with the fractional part set to zero) and is **reset to zero only on a system reboot**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

As you can see, while the sensor is activated, the value will keep increasing without resetting to zero until the system is rebooted.

If you want to count from 0 every time the app is started, you can store the first value returned as initial value, then subtract subsequent value by it.

Comment: do you know how to keep the sensor activated even after closing the app?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975747/flutter-how-can-i-permanently-register-a-sensor-and-never-unregister-it

Answer (score 2):

The Sensor's onSensorChanged method is only called when a real new value appears, it doesn't trigger randomly with repeated values, so if you want to count the steps yourself, you can.

I've chosen to place the steps value inside SharedPreferences, and whenever the onSensorChanged method is triggered I increment the value I have by 1, it's reliable because the sensorChanged method does not trigger for repeated values, this solution works well for me

Comment: This solution works well for me. I put last count at SharedPreference, than i can substract current counter with the value from sharedprefence.

Comment: @odaym, are you sure `onSensorChanged` is called for every single step? I think, sometimes the difference between values of 2 subsequent calls is more than 1. I mean, first call with value N, but second call with N + M (instead of N + 1).

Comment: sure i wouldn't be surprised at all how it behaves, it depends on each device, varies widely even from app to app if you download a bunch of step-counting fitness apps and test them out